# How to use a templated class with static data members across DLL boundary in VC10

Tags: c++, templates, dll

I have a Logging class, which can be simplified to something like:

```
template <int TARGET>
struct Logging
{
  static ostream * sOstream;
  static void log(const char * _txt);
  static void set_log_file(const char * _file_name)
  {
     sOstream = new ofstream(_file_name);
  }
}
```

The whole thing works well in a single binary. However, I'd /like/ to be able to use `Logging<TARGET_DEBUG>::log("some message");` inside a DLL, after having called `Logging<TARGET_DEBUG>::set_log_file(someFilePath.c_str());` in an executable that uses that DLL. Originally, it didn't work because I wasn't exporting the class with `__declspec(dllexport)`. However, when I add the appropriate macro to the logging class definition (header only), I get a series of error messages:

> warning C4273: 'sOstream' : inconsistent dll linkage // why does this occur for a pointer?
>
> error C2491: 'Logging::sOstream' : definition of dllimport static data member not allowed

Various other classes in the application are exported/imported without issue, but this is the only templated class I'm trying to share between binaries.  It's not an area I'm overly familiar with so: how can I make this work as desired? Note the EXE includes the Logging struct with `__declspec(dllimport)`, the DLLs with `__declspec(dllexport)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use explicit template instantiation in conjunction with the `__declspec` modifier. This will cause the template members to be generated *and* exported from the DLL. It will also tell the application accessing the template members that they should be imported rather than generated.

The code below goes into a header file in your DLL project

```
// Normal __declspec import/export stuff
// Define EXPORT_LOGGING in the preprocessor settings of your DLL project 

#ifdef EXPORT_LOGGING
#define LOG_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LOG_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

template <int TARGET>
struct LOG_EXPORT Logging
{
    static std::ostream * sOstream;
    static void log(const char * _txt)
    {
        // ... logging code ...
    }
    static void set_log_file(const char * _file_name)
    {
        sOstream = new std::ofstream(_file_name);
    }
};
```

The code below goes into a `.cpp` file in your DLL project

```
// static member for TARGET_DEBUG
std::ostream* Logging<TARGET_DEBUG>::sOstream = nullptr;

//  explicit template instantiation
template struct Logging<TARGET_DEBUG>;
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks! Only change I made was to define the static members and the explicit instantiation in the template header file, guarded by `#ifdef EXPORT_LOGGING`, so any project that wants this feature need only include the header to make it work. My only remaining concerns are: will this solution work with multiple DLLs that use the same header? And is there an elegant way of making this solution available for a stand-alone executable that doesn't link against a DLL exporting these definitions?

Comment: Yes it will work with multiple modules linking against the main DLL whether they are an EXE or DLL file. You _can_ get it to work stand along with some `#ifdef`'s but whether it's elegant is in the eye of the beholder ;) You could wrap the existing `#ifdef` statements in `#ifdef USE_IN_DLL` and an `#else` that defines `LOG_EXPORT` as empty.